# Emoji JavaEE JSF JBOSS ORACLE

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, oracle11g

Tenho um Sistema WEB e me pediram para colocar emoticons para envio de e-mail.

Tive alguns problemas com a codificação do Banco de dados que é Oracle e o `NLS_CHARACTERSET` estava definido como `WE8MSWIN1252`. Para não alterar a estrutura do banco eu fiz uma solução que salva os emoticons em um campo do tipo `BLOB`, ou seja:

```
// pego esse valor e salvo no BD na coluna Tipo BLOB
String em = emoji.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Para resgatar o valor do emoji como `String` eu faço:

```
// BLOB formatado para string
String em = new String(getEmoji, "UTF-8");
```

Se eu fizer um `System.out.printl(em)` o emoji aparece normalmente no meu console, mas quando eu envio essa `String` para um value do `<h:inputText/>` aparece um diamante negro com um `?`.

Já estou há horas tentando resolver, inclusive alterei as configurações do JBOSS para encoding UTF-8 e os arquivos xhtml estão salvos como UTF-8. Alguém poderia me apontar para alguma direção rumo a solução?

Atualização
O Header do HTML está da seguinte forma:

```
<f:view contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        encoding="UTF-8"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:a="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
        xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
        xmlns:s="http://jboss.com/products/seam/taglib">

       <html>
          <head>
             <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>
             <meta name="author" content="#{applicationService.getPropertyValue('app.fullname')}"/>
             <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="pt-BR"/>
             <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="public, must-revalidate"/>
          </head>
      </html>
</f:view>
```

Atualização

Conforme sugerido pelo Gustavo Fragoso salvei a string do emoji &#x1F354, ao passar o valor para o inputText a string foi convertida para �

Atualização: Conforme sugerido pelo Gustavo Fragoso poderia ser um problema com o meu browser mais não é; estou usando uma biblioteca chamada jQuery-emoji-picker e meu front-end funciona perfeitamente, se eu clicar em algum emoji ele vai normalmente para o input, o problema é quando faço ao contrário ou seja, se a string do emoji vier do banco ou se eu manualmente colar o emoji no value do inputText ao renderizar o html os emojis são convertidos para � ; eu estava quase certo que alguma configuração no JBOSS estava convertendo todo o request e response para outra codificação que não fosse UTF-8; sendo assim fiz um filtro que forçava as requisições HTTP para a codificação UTF-8 e ficou assim:

```
package br.com.dt.filter;

import static org.jboss.seam.ScopeType.APPLICATION;

import static org.jboss.seam.ScopeType.APPLICATION;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Install;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Name;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Scope;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.intercept.BypassInterceptors;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.web.Filter;
import org.jboss.seam.web.AbstractFilter;

@Scope(APPLICATION)
@Name("encodingFilter")
@Install(precedence = Install.BUILT_IN)
@BypassInterceptors
@Filter
public class EncodingFilter  extends AbstractFilter{
    /** Preform the filtering. */
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {  
           response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");  
           request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");  
           response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");  
           chain.doFilter(request, response);  
      }  
}
```

mais sem sucesso, sendo assim configurei o JBOSS no standalone.xml colocando:

```
 system-properties
        property name="file.encoding" value="utf-8"/
        property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING" value="UTF-8"/
        property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.USE_BODY_ENCODING_FOR_QUERY_STRING" value="true"/
    /system-properties
```

mais também sem sucesso até agora.

Atualização:

No Web Resources - Configuration existe vários arquivos de configuração do faces-config.xml e um deles se chama jsf-facelets.jar e veja como esta configurado:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<!DOCTYPE faces-config PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JavaServer Faces Config 1.1//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-facesconfig_1_1.dtd">

<faces-config>
    <component>
        <component-type>facelets.ui.Repeat</component-type>
        <component-class>com.sun.facelets.component.UIRepeat</component-class>
    </component>
    <component>
        <component-type>facelets.ui.ComponentRef</component-type>
        <component-class>com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.ComponentRef</component-class>
    </component>
    <component>
        <component-type>facelets.ui.Debug</component-type>
        <component-class>com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.UIDebug</component-class>
    </component>
    <render-kit>
        <render-kit-id>HTML_BASIC</render-kit-id>
        <renderer>
            <component-family>facelets</component-family>
            <renderer-type>facelets.ui.Repeat</renderer-type>
            <renderer-class>com.sun.facelets.component.RepeatRenderer</renderer-class>
        </renderer>
    </render-kit>
</faces-config>
```

será que essa configuração ISO-8859-1 é a razão desse  problema?

Comment: Seu arquivo html tem um charset definido no header? Salvar como utf-8 é uma coisa, outra é como o navegador interpreta.

Comment: Sim; o cabeçalho esta da seguinte forma:                                             
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />             também defini a f:view como:                                                                            f:view contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    encoding="UTF-8"

Comment: Dê uma olhada nessa questão pra ver se ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42324696/insert-emoji-to-ptexteditor-or-pinputtextarea-on-primefaces?rq=1

Comment: Alex, não precisa colocar `#` no lugar de `<` e `>`. Basta selecionar o código e apertar `Ctrl`+`K` ou o botão `{}` do editor. Veja mais dicas de como formatar o código na [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)